# How do I iterate over the tuples of the items of two or more lists in Python?

Tags: python, loops

Specifically, I have two lists of strings that I'd like to combine into a string where each line is the next two strings from the lists, separated by spaces:

```
a = ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3']
b = ['bar1', 'bar2', 'bar3']
```

I want a function combine_to_lines() that would return:

```
"""foo1 bar1
foo2 bar2
foo3 bar3"""
```

I admit I've already solved this problem, so I'm going to post the answer.  But perhaps someone else has a better one or sees a flaw in mine.

**Update**: I over-simplified my example above.  In my real-world problem the lines were formatted in a more complicated manner that required the tuples returned from zip() to be unpacked.  But kudos to [mhawke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21945/mhawke) for coming up to the simplest solution to this example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not necessary to unpack and repack the tuples returned by zip:

```
'\n'.join(' '.join(x) for x in zip(a, b))
```

Answer (score 9):

The [zip function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) "returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables."

```
def combine_to_lines(list1, list2):
    return '\n'.join([' '.join((a, b)) for a, b in zip(list1, list2)])
```

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> a = ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3']
>>> b = ['bar1', 'bar2', 'bar3']
>>> for i in zip(a,b):
...   print ' '.join(i)
...
foo1 bar1
foo2 bar2
foo3 bar3
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about the [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) function?

Comment: Yes.  I couldn't remember it, and a Google search took a little time to jog my memory.  Perhaps this question will come up in future searches.

Comment: Another question as the answer to the question? :)

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a very old question, but it's interesting to note that this can be seen as a [matrix transposition](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html).

```
>>> import numpy
>>> data = numpy.array([['foo1','foo2','foo3'],['bar1','bar2','bar3']])
>>> print(data)
[['foo1' 'foo2' 'foo3']
 ['bar1' 'bar2' 'bar3']]
>>> print(data.transpose())
[['foo1' 'bar1']
 ['foo2' 'bar2']
 ['foo3' 'bar3']]
```

If you're dealing with a large dataset or more lists this might be a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner.  Could do `x + ' ' + y` if you were so inclined, not sure if it would be slower or not.

```
>>> a = ['foo1', 'foo2' , 'foo3']
>>> b = ['bar1', 'bar2', 'bar3']
>>> '\n'.join(' '.join([x,y]) for (x,y) in zip(a,b))
'foo1 bar1\nfoo2 bar2\nfoo3 bar3'
>>> print _
foo1 bar1
foo2 bar2
foo3 bar3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'\n'.join(((str(x) + ' ' + str(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a, b)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as:

```
" ".join([a[x] + " " + b[x] for x in range(len(a))])
```

Comment: where are the new lines?

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.x:

```
'\n'.join(' '.join(x) for x in zip(a, b))
```

zip returns a list of tuples. zip stops when the shorter of a or b stops.

In python 2.x:

if  itertools.izip would stop when one of the lists ran out of elements but itertools.izip_longest will stop till lists don't have any more elements

```
import itertools
'\n'.join(' '.join(x) for x in itertools.izip(a, b))

'\n'.join(' '.join(x) for x in itertools.izip_longest(a, b))
```

Comment: also credit to mhawke for coming up with the main solution

Comment: Why do you write "In Python 3.x" above? I just confirmed that zip stops when the shorter of a or b stops on Python 2.7.5.

Comment: you're right! 
from what I understand this wasn't a feature in python 2.x before and it was back ported from 3.x am I right? if so from which version i was updated?