# What is a Pythonic way to get a list of tuples of all the possible combinations of the elements of two lists?

Tags: list, python

Suppose I have two differently-sized lists

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ['a', 'b']
```

What is a Pythonic way to get a list of tuples `c` of all the possible combinations of one element from `a` and one element from `b`?

```
>>> print c
[(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'a'), (3, 'b')]
```

The order of elements in `c` does not matter.

The solution with two `for` loops is trivial, but it doesn't seem particularly Pythonic.

Comment: Here are some duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-can-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel-in-python-closed, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126524/iterate-a-list-as-tuples-in-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210396/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-tuples-of-the-items-of-two-or-more-lists-in-python

Comment: @Nathan Fellman - actually, none of those are duplicates.  Please read more carefully before voting to close.

Comment: I must've missed the difference. Is this different because the lists are different length?

Comment: @Nathan Fellman, not only that, but `zip` returns tuples of `(a[0], b[0])`, `(a[1], b[1])`, etc. I want tuples of every possible combination of elements of `a` and `b`.

Comment: @danben, you're absolutely right.  My apologies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `itertools.product`.

Comment: Thanks. Both this and @Moe's answer seem equally valid, so I'm arbitrarily deciding to accept this one because a generator is more useful at this specific point in my code. +1 for both.

Comment: Before I write any code, I always look into the Python standard library, such as operator, itertools, functools and collections.

Answer (score 13):

Use a list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = ['a', 'b']
>>> c = [(x,y) for x in a for y in b]
>>> print c
[(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'a'), (3, 'b')]
```