# Splicing NumPy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am having a problem splicing together two arrays. Let's assume I have two arrays:

```
a = array([1,2,3])
b = array([4,5,6])
```

When I do `vstack((a,b))` I get

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

and if I do `hstack((a,b))` I get:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

But what I really want is:

```
[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

How do I accomplish this without using for loops (it needs to be fast)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I iterate over the tuples of the items of two or more lists in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210396/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-tuples-of-the-items-of-two-or-more-lists-in-python) [how can I iterate through two lists in parallel in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-can-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel-in-python-closed)

Comment: No duplicate; the other threads aren't related to numpy.

Comment: I'm curious why you accepted Philipp's answer, when it was identical to, and submitted later than, Amber's answer?

Comment: @mtrw Because Amber modified his/her answer. He/she suggested vstack first

Comment: @NullUser - Looking at the edit history, the edit only added the `vstack().T` option.

Comment: @mtrw That's because the answer was edited within the 5 minute "grace period." I saw the original.

Comment: @NullUser - That would definitely explain it.  Thanks, and I withdraw my question.

Comment: I actually suggested `dstack` first, not vstack; but then remembered that dstack adds in the 3rd dimension (even if stripping off one dimension then does give the correct answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`column_stack`.

Answer (score 7):

Try `column_stack()`?

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html

Alternatively,

```
vstack((a,b)).T
```

Comment: This creates a three-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot how to transpose NumPy arrays, but you could do:

```
at = transpose(a)
bt = transpose(b)

result = vstack((a,b))
```

Comment: Transposing one-dimensional arrays is an identity operation.

Comment: Feel free to fix the syntax. Like I said, I forgot how to transpose a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> c = [list(x) for x in zip(a,b)]
>>> c
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

or

```
>>> c = np.array([list(x) for x in zip(a,b)])
>>> c
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
```

depending on what you're looking for.

Comment: This question is about NumPy arrays, not lists.

Comment: Yes, but it will most likely be slower than the proper NumPy functions.

Comment: @Amber - True.  I had never stumbled across `column_stack` before, your answer is definitely better.

Answer (score 0):

```
numpy.vstack((a, b)).T
```

Answer (score -1):

You are probably looking for shape manipulation of the array. You can look in the "[Tentative NumPy Tutorial, Array Creation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-d3f8e5fe9b903f3c3b2a5c0dfceb60d71602cf93)".