# Iterate through multiple lists at the same time

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

Is it possible to iterate through multiple lists and return arguments from different lists within the same loop?

I.e., Instead of -

```
For x in trees:
  Print(x) 
For y in bushes:
  Print(y)
```

Something like -

```
For x,y in trees,bushes:
  Print(x +"\n"+ y)
```

Comment: And also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126524/iterate-a-list-as-tuples-in-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210396/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-tuples-of-the-items-of-two-or-more-lists-in-python and probably many more ... :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) or [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
for x, y in zip(trees, bushes):
  print x, y
```

Comment: python2.x also has [`future_builtins.zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/future_builtins.html#future_builtins.zip) which is handy for writing code that works on python2.x and 3.x (Just guard the import statement with a `try: ... except ImportError: pass` suite).

Comment: @mgilson Good point. Python 2.x where x >= 6.

Comment: Oh, did python exist in earlier versions than that ;-).  I can't seem to remember ...

Comment: @mgilson I still run into systems that are on older versions than 2.6. It is painful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip()`:

```
a=['1','2','2']
b=['3','4','5']

for x,y in zip(a,b):
     print(x,y)
```

output:

1 3

2 4

2 5